# UILabel refuses to update

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am having a sort of a weird problem.

I am trying to update a UILabel after returning to a view controller.

When I return to the view controller, I do some work, and then update my views, but none of my UILabels update.

I am 100% sure I am working on the main thread (even tried to force it using dispatch_async and getting the main thread) and it still won't work.

I am also sure that the text property on the UILabel is getting updated, as confirmed by using the print object command in lldb, but it doesn't get updated on screen...

This is the line that changes a UILabel's content, pretty vanilla:

```
[(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1] setText:_accountInfo[@"name"]];
```

This is the output of "po" on that line, immediately after its execution:

```
(lldb) po [self.view viewWithTag:1]
<UILabel: 0x165e87f0; frame = (20 12; 143 21); text = 'Testing Again'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x165de750>>
```

I am using ARC and deploying for iOS 7, by the way.

Should you need any more snippets of code or any information, please say. I am starting to get desperate with this problem here!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Forgot to add that this same code works when I first setup the view.

Comment: have you assigned tagged to label on storyboard?

Comment: I think we need more code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the below steps:

1) If you have added labels from your code. Check that you are allocating memory and initializing the labels.

2) If you have drag & dropped the label in Interface Builder check if you have given proper tags and done necessary outlet connections.

3) Check if that the tags of the labels and other views are not conflicting.

4) Clean all targets using cmd+shift+k.

5) Build again

OR

Check using this to verify if it is a label or not:

```
if ([[self.view viewWithTag:1] isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
    //Its a label
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    label.text=@"Hello World";
}
else {
    //Its not a label
}
```

May be you should try the second option. You will get atleast some idea of what is happening..

Comment: The code works when I first setup the view, on viewDidLoad, so it is not a tag issue. Also, it is a label, as verified by the print object output of lldb.

Comment: May be you are having 2 labels with the same tag.

Comment: I fixed it. I actually had two labels with the same tag, but they were childs of different views. It was working on viewDidLoad because that other labels were still not initialized, for sure. To clarify, I had a label with tag 1 on the main view, and lots of views with tag 1 on cells of a tableview, child of that view. I still think this is a bug of iOS, and will report it, but got it fixed thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this...

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
label.text = _accountInfo[@"name"];
```

Comment: This didn't fix it. Read my Edit please.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this:

```
[((UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1]) setText:_accountInfo[@"name"]];
```

Comment: This didn't fix it. Read my Edit please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set dynamic font for ios7
Try This...

```
UIFontDescriptor *userFont = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
float userFontSize = [userFont pointSize];
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:userFontSize];//[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:userFontSize];
[noteLabel setFont:font];
```

Comment: This didn't fix it. Read my Edit please.